# How to ensure focused before taking picture in Android CameraX? (Should be a very commonly used feature!)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera, android-camerax

I am using CameraX and want to take a photo. Of course, no one wants a blurred picture, so we should ensure focused before taking picture.

First attempt: Simply call `takePicture` like what is done in the [official sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/README.md).

Problem: I can change the scene and quickly press the take photo button. Then, the camera has not finished auto focus when the takePicture happens. Therefore, I get a blurred photo :/

Second attempt: Before actually taking photo, firstly trigger focusing and wait for it to finish.

Code like:

```
camera!!.cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(
                    FocusMeteringAction.Builder(
                            autoFocusPoint,
                            FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF
                    ).apply {
                        //focus only when the user tap the preview
                        disableAutoCancel()
                    }.build()
            )
```

Problem: It takes so long to do a focus (seconds!). Users definitely cannot accept that.

Therefore, I wonder what should I do? IMHO this should be very commonly used, so I am surprised to see that I cannot find any solution! Do I miss something?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How much seconds does it take for focusing ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar A few seconds, depending on the phone model. However, I have tried other apps which have "taking photos" features. They do **not** require a full focus, if the camera is already focused. Notice that my second attempt is that, **always** require a full focus, even if it is already focused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! Simply call `setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)`.

Reason: look at ImageCapture's constructor:

```
        if (mCaptureMode == CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY) {
            mEnableCheck3AConverged = true; // check 3A convergence in MAX_QUALITY mode
        } else {
            mEnableCheck3AConverged = false; // skip 3A convergence in MIN_LATENCY mode
        }
```

And that field:

```
    /**
     * A flag to check 3A converged or not.
     *
     * <p>In order to speed up the taking picture process, trigger AF / AE should be skipped when
     * the flag is disabled. Set it to be enabled in the maximum quality mode and disabled in the
     * minimum latency mode.
     */
    private final boolean mEnableCheck3AConverged;
```

Aha!